# I want to edit the last part of the date from "20" to "2015" Which function should I use?

Tags: r

```
 [1] "18-12-20" "18-12-20" "04-12-20" "27-11-20" "12-11-20" "30-10-20" "30-10-20"
 [8] "30-10-20" "22-10-20" "16-10-20" "09-10-20" "02-10-20" "02-10-20" "25-09-20"
[15] "25-09-20" "18-09-20" "11-09-20" "04-09-20" "28-08-20" "21-08-20" "21-08-20"
[22] "14-08-20" "07-08-20" "31-07-20" "17-07-20" "03-07-20" "26-06-20" "19-06-20"
[29] "12-06-20" "05-06-20" "28-05-20" "22-05-20" "15-05-20" "08-05-20" "08-05-20"
[36] "01-05-20" "17-04-20" "10-04-20" "20-03-20" "13-03-20" "06-03-20" "27-02-20"
[43] "27-02-20" "20-02-20" "13-02-20" "06-02-20" "30-01-20" "30-01-20" "23-01-20"
[50] "23-01-20" "16-01-20" "09-01-20"
```

How to replace the last part of the string with a new string ?
I want to replace the last part "20" with "2015"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: use the `gsub()` function:

`gsub("*20$", replacement = "2015", x = "your_string_name" )`

Comment: @J_F well, this will also replace any date with value 20.

Comment: you are right ... edited my comment

Comment: haha..right! but that is now my answer :-)

Comment: okay, I'll ask. is this a character vector or a date vector

Comment: @DeepakBhattacharya you can accept any answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

`gsub` will work fine for this

```
gsub("-20", "-2015", df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sub`.

`*20` means it can accommodate anything before 20 whereas `$` in the end ensures that it is the end of vector and nothing is present after that. Hence, this helps in case if there is date with value `20`.

```
sub("*20$", "2015", x)
```

where `x` is the vector you want to replace.

Comment: This wont replace any date with 20 ? i just want to edit the year from 20 to 2015

Comment: Can you please explain the use of various symbols like *,$,^ while using sub.Thanks

Comment: Thanks :) That was really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to `paste` "15" to the end of each element:

```
temp <- c("18-12-20", "18-12-20", "04-12-20")
paste(temp, "15", sep="")
[1] "18-12-2015" "18-12-2015" "04-12-2015"
```

or

```
paste0(temp, "15")
```